# Replace fragment after orientation change crash

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When user changes screen orientation and execute "goToDetails" the FragmentManager throws

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Class code:

```
@ActivityScope
class NavigatorImpl @Inject constructor(): ActivityLifecycleTask(), Navigator {

private lateinit var fragmentManager: FragmentManager

@IdRes
private var fragmentContainerRes: Int = 0

override fun onCreate(activity: BaseActivity) {
    fragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager
    fragmentContainerRes = activity.fragmentContainerRes()
}

override fun init(fragment: BaseFragment) {
    goToFragment(fragment, TAG_INIT_FRAGMENT)
}

override fun goToDetails(id: Long) {
    goToFragment(DetailsFragment.create(id))
}

private fun goToFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String? = null) {
    Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "goToFragment")
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(fragmentContainerRes, fragment, tag)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
}

companion object {
    private const val TAG_INIT_FRAGMENT = "TAG_INIT_FRAGMENT"
}
}
```

The `commitAllowingInstanceStateLoss()` is not working. 
The `onCreate(activity)` is executed in Activity `onCreate` callback. Then while `savedInstanceState == null`, the `init()` from NavigatorImpl is executed.

Comment: add check if activity is destroyed in `goToFragment`

Answer (score 2):

When you rotate screen your Activity's `onCreate` will execute but it's `savedInstanceState` will not be `null`. If you do not check if it's noll or not, still you'll try to commit a new transaction to init your acitivity. So you should check if `savedInstanceState == null` before init your fragments.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // commit your fragment transaction.
    }
}
```